# Accessing request.META.SERVER_NAME in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-settings

I call a template like this from my view:

```
return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm trying to access the hostname of my current server (in this case, `localhost`), but it just prints blank when I place `{{request.META.SERVER_NAME}}` in the template.

In my `settings.py` file, I don't have any `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` defined.  I'm not sure if I need to specify anything there, or if that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `request` context processor to have it added to the template context automatically. Or you could explicitly add the request to the context dictionary `render_to_response('foo', {'request': request})`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request

Note that if you add the request context processor, you should remember to add [the defaults](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) as well.

Comment: Thanks.  Now it returns `1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa` instead of `localhost` though.  Any idea on that?

Comment: @babonk, that's a different question that I can't answer as I'm not very familiar with headers.

Comment: Got it with `request.get_host()`.  Thanks for the help