# get_host vs META['SERVER_NAME'] and 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa

Tags: python, django, macos

I'm looking at some code and it's using request.META['SERVER_NAME'] and checking if the first 9 characters match 'localhost'. In osx the value of SERVER_NAME is '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa', but if I do request.get_host() I get localhost:10002 (which is the way I access it in my browser). Other developers running the same code in linux and windows gets localhost as the value from META.

I've seen two other people asking related questions (in the comment section to the answer) [Accessing request.META.SERVER_NAME in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073342/accessing-request-meta-server-name-in-template) and https://plus.google.com/+SamVilain/posts/8TortHZ7J5V. But I haven't found a way to have it behave the way I want. So my question: Is there a simple way to make django populate META[SERVER_NAME] with localhost? This is a rather large system and the check is made in lots of places so changing the variable for the call is something I'd really like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to fix another issue I had with the terminal showing a random hostname as the terminal prompt did I stumble upon scutil. Turned out when I ran the following command it also fixed my issue with django:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the reverse

> sudo scutil --set HostName 1.0.0.127

then went into the host config file

> sudo nano /etc/hosts

and added

> 1.0.0.127       127.0.0.1

tricking the system to return 127.0.0.1